# Separate queries in MongoDB with ;

Tags: mongodb, atomic, database

Quick question.

I have a number of update commands to run on my MongoDB database. These happen after a user has completed a number of tasks and wants to push all updates to the server. I will update several documents in several collections.

If I want to assure that these updates are atomic and no other simultaneous queries or commands from other users can interfere, can I separate my queries with `;`?

Simplified example:

```
db.cities.find({"asciiname":"Zamin Sukhteh"});db.cities.find({"asciiname":"Konab-e Vasat"})
```

Will the above result in two separate and atomic queries?

Comment: I should note that this is from a Mongo shell standpoint as that is what I use to manage the database. And by atomic I refer to this: [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/)

Comment: No, MongoDB does not have capabilities for multiple atomic queries like that in a single call, that will actually result in two separate calls to the database that are not atomic, since atomicity runs on write not reads

Comment: Okay, I only used that as an easy/bad example. Can I separate update commands with a ';' for atomicity?

Comment: No, MongoDB unlike SQL does not have the capability. It is one command per query document atm

Comment: I see. So the best approach is to send each single document update command separately and mongo will prevent them from interfering with other commands that way?

Comment: Yes MongoDB has a DB level write lock

Comment: If you are looking for transactional support, you should consider some of the design patterns suggested in the MongoDB documentation such as [Isolated sequence of operations (Update if current)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/) or [Two phase commits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/).  For your particular case, the "isolate sequence of operations" seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't use a delimiter to separate commands in the shell to introduce atomicity, you can use db.eval.

If you're only using the shell (which you said in comments), you can use the [db.eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/#db.eval) function to perform a database-wide lock while executing a block of JavaScript code. It's not something you'd normally want to do (as it blocks all writes and reads by default), but in the case that you're describing above (again, the comments), it sounds like it would fit your needs.

```
db.eval( function() {
    var one = db.cities.find({"asciiname":"Zamin Sukhteh"});
    var two = db.cities.find({"asciiname":"Konab-e Vasat"});
    // other work ...
});
```

Update (to address a comment):

If you want efficient atomic (-like) updates in MongoDB, there are a few options:

1. Put everything in a single document. This is guaranteed atomic in MongoDB. However, that often doesn't work for complex document models (or large documents).
2. If there are dependencies on a document, consider placing new "versions" of the dependent documents, and then, only after those are all set, put the final document linking those documents together into the DB. Without the final "link", older documents shouldn't see the new versions. Depending on how the data is consumed, it's likely you could remove the older versions quite rapidly (or periodically if desired).
3. Accept that there will occasionally be mismatches and detect them (and then rerun the query to get fresh data). You might be able to use a timestamp or version to identify these cases as you traverse through your document structure.
4. Cache the data elsewhere as a full-structure for common queries
5. Decide MongoDB isn't a good fit for your requirements.

Comment: that's like taking a hammer to a problem that needs a screw driver

Comment: With power comes great responsibility. :) The shell is extremely powerful and can be dangerous. If it's only work from the shell, I don't see it as terrible if its infrequent (and I'd definitely not recommend it on a production server).

Comment: I usually evaluate my queries from the shell to get desired results, then pass them along to my Android developer who implements them in the app. He uses Php and Java to talk to the database so no shell for him, but I am going by the assumption that he can translate my commands to the appropriate code.

Comment: My concern is that at the end of a user process (recording a GPS track) the app will create a recording document, update user statistics for how many tracks have been recorded, update a route document, update a vehicle document and so forth. Since I will have thousands of users doing this over and over again, I became worried about atomicity of the operations so that they don't interfere with each other. I read that one write/update operation is atomic in Mongodb's sense, but I was mostly wondering how I can stack multiple updates after each other without breaking integrity.

Comment: Added a few ideas in my answer to reflect this new detail. (Summary -- there's no perfect solution).

Comment: Abusing a locking side effect of `db.eval` is a particularly poor way to implement multi-document transactional behaviour .. definitely not recommendable, and guaranteed to provide poor performance.